# How to disable a firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a demo realtime database on firebase console. There is no data in it yet. I want to deactivate & delete this demo realtime database, but don't know how.

The Disable button is grey, indicating I need to remove data before disabling. But I cannot find the data anywhere.

[image: a demo realtime database cannot be deactivated]

Answer (score 0):

Check if this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70087620/what-is-the-reason-for-jwt-authentication-required-error) is usefull.

It seems that all you have to do is set these rules in the rules tab of your database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```