# What is the reason for JWT Authentication Required error?

Tags: jwt, google-cloud-storage

I have created a [JWT](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount) using the guide at the end of the page. However, when I make a request, I get back the code "AuthenticationRequired" and the message "Authentication required." I have verified that it is a valid JWT with RS256 algorithm. What could be the reason for the JWT to not be recognized?

I am able to make the same request with an access token but not JWT. I am using jsonwebtoken npm library, but I have also used PyJWT and received the same error.

Edit: JWT does work for Google Cloud Storage.

```
curl --request GET \
  --url <https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket}/{path}> \
  --header ‘Authorization: Bearer <JWT>’ \
  --header ‘Content-Type: text/plain’
```

jwt code:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

    const acc = '<service-account-email>'
    const iat = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000)
    const exp = Math.floor(iat + (365 * 86400))
    const PRIVATE_KEY_ID_FROM_JSON = '<key-id>'
    const PRIVATE_KEY_FROM_JSON = '<private_key_from_json>'
    const additional_headers = { 'kid': PRIVATE_KEY_ID_FROM_JSON }
    const token = jwt.sign({
        'iss': acc,
        'sub': acc,
        'aud': 'storage.googleapis.com',
        'iat': iat,
        'exp': exp
    }, PRIVATE_KEY_FROM_JSON, { header: additional_headers, algorithm: 'RS256'  });
```

Comment: What service are you calling? Most Google Cloud APIs require OAuth Tokens. For those that do accept a signed JWT (signed by Google issued private key), include your code so that we can help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks! I have modified to show I am creating the jwt. I am calling storage.googleapis.com, and it has worked before for a different bucket.

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not accept a Signed JWT for authorization. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67911916/8016720

Comment: @JohnHanley, this logic has worked before on another bucket. I'm not sure if it's down to permissions issues or parsing errors.

Comment: Two items are masked in your question. What is **acc** and **url**? You can mask the email, bucket name, and object name, but make them technically understandable. How long ago do you believe that this worked? Are you sure the code did not exchange the JWT for an OAuth Token? To quote Google: **Cloud Storage uses OAuth 2.0 for API authentication and authorization.** https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication